# Material table cells with specific width according to predefined length

Tags: css, typescript, angular-material

I will show my code first.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Everything works fine, my requirement is to display text but just a fixed length of it. For example, if I have a text that is `50` characters long, the requirement is to display `40`. I have many cells in each row, many cells of fixed length.

To clarify, here my difficulty is how to set width with some text length, I saw many examples but the column width was set in the CSS file. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve this is to set the width of the `td` via Angular's built in `[ngStyle]` with some calculation of the element's length.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
      [ngStyle]="{'max-width': ((element.name.length) - 20) + 'ch', 'overflow': 'hidden' }">
      {{element.name}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Here the `max-width` (in `ch`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)) of the element is defined by `element.name.length` minus `20` (specify as you like). Also `overflow: hidden` is set, so the rest of the text won't be shown inside the table cell.

See below for the differences between a **fixed table** and **normal table**.

#### Fixed table

[image: Fixed table with smaller td set]

#### Normal table

[image: Normal table, no smaller td set]

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebirsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html) to illustrate above.

Comment: Thanks Roy, i'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**
You can set maxCharLength as per your requirements. Also mat-table doesn't need  `<th>` or `<td>` tags.

```
<ng-container  matColumnDef="position">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="element.position" [maxCharLength]="40">
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```